# How do I convert a set of basic (non-nested) views into a single nested query?

Tags: sql, postgresql, psql

I have used a sequence of basic non-nested SQL View queries to slowly filter data from multiple tables to obtain a result I was after. The first query has used base relations as the input, the subsequent queries have used the base relations and/or the results from the previous query. The final query has displayed the result I was after.

First query:

```
CREATE VIEW ActiveRobbers
AS
SELECT a.RobberID, Nickname, NoYears, BankName, Share
FROM info.Robber a, info.Accomplices b
WHERE a.RobberID = b.RobberID;
```

[image: Result from first query]

Second query:

```
CREATE VIEW ActiveRobbers2
AS
SELECT Nickname, NoYears, COUNT(RobberID) AS NoRobberies, SUM(Share) AS    TotalEarnings
FROM ActiveRobbers
GROUP BY Nickname, NoYears;
```

[image: Result from second query]

Final query:

```
CREATE VIEW ActiveRobbers3
AS  
SELECT Nickname
FROM ActiveRobbers2
WHERE NoYears = 0
AND NoRobberies > (SELECT AVG(NoRobberies) FROM ActiveRobbers2);
```

[image: Result from third query]

How would I go about converting this into a single nested query using select statements? Is there some sort of rule you can use? Do I work backwards because of the nesting?

Comment: The good news is: you don't need to. The planner will do it for you. (check the resulting query plans)

Comment: This sounds good. Where do I find this? Using the admin? Sorry I am quite new to SQL

Comment: Just prefix your query with `EXPLAIN ` to obtain the plan. `EXPLAIN ANALYZE ` also executes the query (throwing away the result) and gives you the plan and execution timings.

Answer (score 0):

If you are learning SQL, learn to use correct and explicit `join` syntax.  So your first query would be:

```
SELECT r.RobberID, a.Nickname, a.NoYears, a.BankName, a.Share
FROM info.Robber r JOIN
     info.Accomplices a
     on r.RobberID = a.RobberID;
```

The second:

```
SELECT a.Nickname, a.NoYears, COUNT(*) as NumRobberies, SUM(Share) as TotalEarnings
FROM info.Robber r JOIN
     info.Accomplices a
     on r.RobberID = a.RobberID
GROUP BY a.Nickname, a.NoYears
```

And the third:

```
WITH ActiveRobbers2 as (
      SELECT a.Nickname, a.NoYears, COUNT(*) as NumRobberies, SUM(Share) as TotalEarnings
      FROM info.Robber r JOIN
           info.Accomplices a
           on r.RobberID = a.RobberID
      GROUP BY a.Nickname, a.NoYears
     )
SELECT a.*
FROM ActiveRobbers2 a
WHERE NoYears = 0 AND
      NumRobberies > (SELECT AVG(NumRobberies) FROM ActiveRobbers2);
```

Actually, I would write the third version using window functions, but I'm leaving your logic as it is in the question.